# Callback on image browse event for angular-bootstrap-lightbox

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, lightbox, angular-bootstrap

I am using [angular-bootstrap-lightbox](https://github.com/compact/angular-bootstrap-lightbox) and would like to add a callback function when the image is changed.

Specifically, on the mobile view, when a user swipes right or left, I want to get the image id, as well as the direction of the swipe.

This code works fine to initialize the lightbox:

```
$scope.openLightboxModal = function(index) {
  Lightbox.openModal($scope.images, index);
}
```

How do I add a callback function to the above so as to register the image change event?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

On this line in the `angular-bootstrap-lightbox.js` file:

https://github.com/compact/angular-bootstrap-lightbox/blob/0cfd9aea6e1ed7a192614c6ee4480e13dfdfbeb9/dist/angular-bootstrap-lightbox.js#L13

You can change thit `ng-swipe-right=Lightbox.prevImage()` to something like `ng-swipe-right=Lightbox.myFunction()` and in my controller, I have access to that  event!